# Fastest algorithm to identify the smallest and largest x that make the double-precision equation x + a == b true

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754

In the context of static analysis, I am interested in determining the values of `x` in the then-branch of the conditional below:

```
double x;
x = …;
if (x + a == b)
{
  …
```

`a` and `b` can be assumed to be double-precision constants (generalizing to arbitrary expressions is the easiest part of the problem), and the compiler can be assumed to follow IEEE 754 strictly (`FLT_EVAL_METHOD` is 0). The rounding mode at run-time can be assumed to be to nearest-even.

If computing with rationals was cheap, it would be simple: the values for `x` would be the double-precision numbers contained in the rational interval (b - a - 0.5 * ulp1(b) … b - a + 0.5 * ulp2(b)). The bounds should be included if `b` is even, excluded if `b` is odd, and ulp1 and ulp2 are two slightly different definitions of “ULP” that can be taken identical if one does not mind losing a little precision on powers of two.

Unfortunately, computing with rationals can be expensive. Consider that another possibility is to obtain each of the bounds by dichotomy, in 64 double-precision additions (each operation deciding one bit of the result). 128 floating-point additions to obtain the lower and upper bounds may well be faster than any solution based on maths.

I am wondering if there is a way to improve over the “128 floating-point additions” idea. Actually I have my own solution involving changes of rounding mode and `nextafter` calls, but I wouldn't want to cramp anyone's style and cause them to miss a more elegant solution than the one I currently have. Also I am not sure that changing the rounding mode twice is actually cheaper than 64 floating-point additions.

Comment: Could you use binary search to bisect to the values that you want? It would seem like this should be possible since the number of bits is low.

Comment: @templatetypedef the “128 floating-point additions” solution I sketch out is a binary search over the representation of floating-point numbers, and the one that I don't want to show because I don't know if it is actually an improvement reduces the initial interval to bisect by computing an over-approximated range of candidates, that would then need to be refined by binary search.

Comment: @templatetypedef I am sort of hoping that someone will come up with a theorem of floating-point arithmetics that solves the problem more elegantly.

Comment: Have you considered hybrid approaches? Do some analysis of the numbers to get the approximate range, then refine using binary search.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan The solution I didn't want to show is to start from the range rd(nextafter(b, -INFINITY) - a) … ru(nextafter(b, +INFINITY) - a) as initial approximation of the lower bound, then use either bitwise operations on the floating-point representation or floating-point arithmetics to refine the result. Then refine the upper bound starting from the same initial interval.

Comment: I'll try to think of something else, but that was my best initial idea.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Seems like you can get `ulp1` and `ulp2` using a couple `nextafter`s and subtractions.  If `a` and `b` have the same sign, Sterbenz's theorem tells you that `b-a` is exact and it's also at most `b`.  What about scaling `ulp1` and `ulp2` up by `1 + 0x1p-52` before pushing the bounds out, then just testing two or three nearby values?  (Don't have time to flesh this out right now.  I guess I'll post it as an answer now and work on it later.)

Comment: @tmyklebu You lost me at “If a and b have the same sign, Sterbenz's theorem tells you that b-a is exact”. What if `a` is 1 and `b` is `0x1.0p80`? The Sterbenz theorem I know is for b/2 ≤ a ≤ 2*b.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Oops, yeah.  I wrote lies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already gave a nice and elegant solution in your question:

> If computing with rationals was cheap, it would be simple: the values
>   for x would be the double-precision numbers contained in the rational
>   interval (b - a - 0.5 * ulp1(b) … b - a + 0.5 * ulp2(b)). The bounds
>   should be included if b is even, excluded if b is odd, and ulp1 and
>   ulp2 are two slightly different definitions of “ULP” that can be taken
>   identical if one does not mind losing a little precision on powers of
>   two.

What follows is a half-reasoned sketch of a partial solution to the problem based on this paragraph.  Hopefully I'll get a chance to flesh it out soon.  To get a real solution, you'll have to handle subnormals, zeroes, NaNs, and all that other fun stuff.  I'm going to assume that `a` and `b` are, say, such that `1e-300 < |a| < 1e300` and `1e-300 < |b| < 1e300` so that no craziness occurs at any point.

Absent overflow and underflow, you can get `ulp1(b)` from `b - nextafter(b, -1.0/0.0)`.  You can get `ulp2(b)` from `nextafter(b, 1.0/0.0) - b`.

If `b/2 <= a <= 2b`, then Sterbenz's theorem tells you that `b - a` is exact.  So `(b - a) - ulp1 / 2` will be the closest `double` to the lower bound and `(b - a) + ulp2 / 2` will be the closest `double` to the upper bound.  Try these values, and the values immediately before and after, and pick the widest interval that works.

If `b > 2a`, `b - a > b/2`.  The computed value of `b - a` is off by at most half an ulp.  One `ulp1` is at most two ulp, as is one `ulp2`, so the rational interval you gave is at most two ulp wide.  Figure out which of the five closest values to `b-a` work.

If `a > 2b`, an ulp of `b-a` is at least as big as an ulp of `b`; if anything works, I bet it'll have to be be among the three closest values to `b-a`.  I imagine the case where `a` and `b` have different signs works similarly.

I wrote a small pile of C++ code implementing this idea.  It didn't fail random fuzz testing (in a few different ranges) before I got bored of waiting.  Here it is:

```
void addeq_range(double a, double b, double &xlo, double &xhi) {
  if (a != a) return; // empty interval
  if (b != b) {
    if (a-a != 0) { xlo = xhi = -a; return; }
    else return; // empty interval
  }
  if (b-b != 0) {
    // TODO: handle me.
  }

  // b is now guaranteed to be finite.
  if (a-a != 0) return; // empty interval

  if (b < 0) {
    addeq_range(-a, -b, xlo, xhi);
    xlo = -xlo;
    xhi = -xhi;
    return;
  }

  // b is now guaranteed to be zero or positive finite and a is finite.
  if (a >= b/2 && a <= 2*b) {
    double upulp = nextafter(b, 1.0/0.0) - b;
    double downulp = b - nextafter(b, -1.0/0.0);
    xlo = (b-a) - downulp/2;
    xhi = (b-a) + upulp/2;
    if (xlo + a == b) {
      xlo = nextafter(xlo, -1.0/0.0);
      if (xlo + a != b) xlo = nextafter(xlo, 1.0/0.0);
    } else xlo = nextafter(xlo, 1.0/0.0);
    if (xhi + a == b) {
      xhi = nextafter(xhi, 1.0/0.0);
      if (xhi + a != b) xhi = nextafter(xhi, -1.0/0.0);
    } else xhi = nextafter(xhi, -1.0/0.0);
  } else {
    double xmid = b-a;
    if (xmid + a < b) {
      xhi = xlo = nextafter(xmid, 1.0/0.0);
      if (xhi + a != b) xhi = xmid;
    } else if (xmid + a == b) {
      xlo = nextafter(xmid, -1.0/0.0);
      xhi = nextafter(xmid, 1.0/0.0);
      if (xlo + a != b) xlo = xmid;
      if (xhi + a != b) xhi = xmid;
    } else {
      xlo = xhi = nextafter(xmid, -1.0/0.0);
      if (xlo + a != b) xlo = xmid;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was hoping that someone would find. One question though: reading from my phone, I don't see the place where you had to worry about the representation of the empty set when the empty set is indeed the best answer (`x + 1.0 == 0x1.0p-80`, for instance)

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I'm inconsistent about that.  Dealing with the NaN/infinity cases, I just return.  Later on, I return with `xlo > xhi`.