# Finding smallest float x such that x+d=y

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

How to find the smallest `float`/`double` number `x` which satisfies `x + d = y` given `d` and `y`?

(iiuc this is theoretically solved via setting `fesetround (FE_DOWNWARD)` and just doing `y - d` but in clang/Xcode I got a warning that `FENV_ACCESS` isn't supported and in practice found that it didn't work)

So, so far I made this:

```
// Find minimum x value so that x + d = y
template<typename T, bool supportDenormals = false>
T subtractMost (const T y, const T d)
{
    T x = y - d;
    while (true)
    {
        const T nextX =
            x == 0 && !supportDenormals
            ? -std::numeric_limits<T>::min()
            : nextafter (x, -std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity());
        if (nextX + d != y)
            return x;
        T step = x - nextX;
        while (true)
        {
            const T nextStep = step + step;
            if (x - nextStep + d != y)
                break;
            step = nextStep;
        }
        x -= step;
    }
}
```

Which does quite a lot of actions to find the result, but I wonder:

Is there's a more efficient solution or a more standard way to achieve this?

Comment: Does `std::nexttoward` help?  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter

Comment: @RichardCritten: It does in the sense that I've used it (`std::nextafter` to be precise) in my current solution. But I still wonder if there's a better way..

Comment: I think `nextafter` is not the wrong tool here: for `y = -d = 10E9`, you begin you loop from `0` whereas precision is far from that.

Comment: Working with `d/y` might be a better approach (to have good precision).

Comment: Do you want the solution for the current rounding mode, or always for round-to-nearest-even? What if no such `x` exists, e.g., for `d=1e30`, `y=1e-30` (or if one element is not finite)?

Comment: @chtz: "What if no such x exists" - Good question, I guess in that case the function could return an exceptional value.
"Do you want the solution for the current rounding mode" - Basically what I'm trying to do is equivalent to what rounding modes should provide, it's just that I tried to use them and got a warning from the compiler that those are not supported..

Comment: @Jarod42 "you begin you loop from 0 whereas precision is far from that" but after a logarithmic number of iterations the step becomes more relevant. Can you describe an answer based on your `d/y` approach? I'm not sure what it is that you suggest..

Comment: Your question is subsumed by [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222822/fastest-algorithm-to-identify-the-smallest-and-largest-x-that-make-the-double-pr) that I asked some time ago. I have some extra insights, gained since I asked that question, in case you are interested in the cases where `d` and `y` vary in an interval and/or solutions for `x` should be found inside an initial interval.

Comment: “generalizing to arbitrary expressions is the easiest part of the problem” in my question is not true at all, it turned out. When `d` and `y` are allowed to vary in intervals, then the set of solutions for `x` is not always an interval. This means that an approach such as the one you suggest does not work: you may accidentally skip over the smallest solution.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Do you have example `d` and `y` values where `x` is not an interval?

Comment: @yairchu My remark was only if `d` is allowed to be in an interval. In this case, take `y = 2.0`, `d` in the range [1.5, 1.75]. Then 0.25 is a solution for `x`, but the three double that come after 0.25 aren't solutions of the equation for any value of `d`, and the fourth successor of 0.25 (`0x1.0000000000004p-2`) is again a solution. https://godbolt.org/g/fxDa64